# PostgreSQL constraint on default address

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have a User table and Address table. There is a 1:N relation between them (User can have multiple Addresses). In my application, User can select a default Address (isDefault: true).

Can you help me to write SQL constraint that would ensure that only one Address is set as default for a particular User, please? (when setting a new Address as default, the constraint should make the previously default Address non default - isDefault: false).

Answer (score 4):

You can create a filtered unique index.

The exact setup depends on the actual definition of the tables, but if you have an `address` table (where `address_id` is the primary key, rather than a foreign key) and `user_id` is a foreign key to the `users` table, you can use:

```
create unique index only_one_default_address 
    on address (user_id) 
where is_default;
```

This will prevent two default addresses for the same user, but allows unlimited non-default addresses.

---

However no constraint will ever *change* data, so the requirement "*when setting a new Address as default, the constraint should make the previously default Address non default*" has to be implemented using a trigger.

```
create or replace function reset_default_address()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin  
  if new.is_default then 
     update address
       set is_default = false
     where user_id = new.user_id;
  end if;
  return new;
end;  
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger trg_change_default_address
  before update or insert on address
  for each row
  when (new.is_default)
  execute procedure reset_default_address();
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b3a811db4d365fffe5527bc3dfd06d88)

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest solution is to have a separate 1:1 table "DefaultAddresses" with a unique (UserId, AddressId) index.

As an alternative, assuming `isDefault` column, you can try unique index on `Addresses` table, on `UserId` column `(...) WHERE isDefault`.

Automatic update can only be done via custom trigger function. I advice doing that on the application level though.

Comment: That is a nice workaround, I'll consider it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXCLUDE` constraint, using `user` and `address` table pk and fk keys.

```
ALTER TABLE address
    ADD CONSTRAINT ex_address_is_default EXCLUDE USING gist (
    user_id WITH =,
    address_uid WITH =)
    WHERE (isDefault IS TRUE);
```